# I keep getting nothing but 0 for the score

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate score for a problem, and I created this code as a sort of sandbox area for my main code. This function is supposed to calculate score as determined by what space the person lands on.

Example: they land on an add space, whatever number is after add in the list gets added to the score.

I decided to split the items in the list and then use a for loop and if statement to go through every item in the list and check what the operation was and then calculate the score, but I keep getting nothing but 0 as the score. The list separates fine but it doesn't calculate the score correctly.

```
game_map = ['nop', 'mul 65', 'sub 20', 'add 75', 'hlt']
pos = 0
map_split = [map.split() for map in game_map]
print(map_split)
score = 0
for j in range(0, len(map_split)):
    if "mul" in map_split:
        score *= int(map_split[j][1])
    elif "sub" in map_split:
        score -= int(map_split[j][1])
    elif "add" in map_split:
        score += int(map_split[j][1])
    elif "nop" in map_split:
        score = score
    elif "jmp" in map_split:
        score = score

    print(score)
```

Comment: You're creating a nested list so `in map_split` doesn't work

Comment: "mul" is, in fact, _not_ in map_split.  The _sublist_ `["mul", "65"]` is.

Comment: Your conditional checks are wrong because you are always checking if a certain string is in `map_split` which is a list of lists. So none of your conditions will ever yield true. You have to change them to `[...] in map_split[j][0]` in order to work

Comment: so like: if ['mul'] in map_split[j][0]:

Comment: Why are you iterating over `range` instead of iterating over the list itself, you're not using the index anywhere

Comment: so then how should i do it im pretty new to python

Comment: Also, what is the point of the last two `elif` statements that just assign `score` to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for j in map_split:
    if "mul" in j:
        score *= int(j[1])
    elif "sub" in j:
        score -= int(j[1])
    elif "add" in j:
        score += int(j[1])
    print(score)
```

Comment: You're welcome,  consider accepting the answer.